# Rails Table Column with specific name always returns nil

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Setting up a very standard model and migration:

```
class CreateLinks < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :links do |t|
      t.string      :slug
      t.text        :tracking_url
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

When filling out a form (or populating in rails console) I can save to model attribute `:tracking_url` and it appears when I query the entire object. However, when I query the specific attribute (e.g `link.tracking_url`) nil is always returned. Querying works in the standard way for all other attributes and even if I change `:tracking_url` to `:tracking`, or anything else.

Very confusing does anyone have an explaination for this?

Comment: Are you permitting `tracking_url` when you create a new record? Can you post your logs when you create a new link record and controller code too?

Comment: Can you add a new record from the rails console?